# Loading TikZ3+PSTricks at the same time

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, barcodes, pst-barcode

> I am also posting my solution. Please save your time and energy on this Question!

I have experienced a strange behavior after upgrading TikZ 2 to TikZ 3 when loading and using the TikZ and PSTricks packages (via `auto-pst-pdf`) at the same time. Please consider this situation of generating barcodes.

```
%! latex or pdflatex or xelatex or lualatex
%! with ----shell-escape or --enable-write18
%! bug0001-problem.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
My first barcode is:\par
\begin{pspicture}(3,1in)
\psbarcode{978-80-87106-00-6}{includetext guardwhitespace}{isbn}
\end{pspicture}\par
My first QR code is:\par
\begin{pspicture}(1,1in)
\psbarcode{http://www.cstug.cz/}{}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}\par
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{Hello World!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I had no problem when using TikZ 2, but I got this error message with TikZ 3.

> Error: /typecheck in --div--
>
> Operand stack:
>
> 1   2   0.0   TeXcolorgray   65781.8
>
> Execution stack:
>
> %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1932   1   3   %oparray_pop   1931   1   3   %oparray_pop   1915   1   3   %oparray_pop   1803   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   5   --nostringval--   %repeat_continue   --nostringval--
>
> Dictionary stack:
>
> --dict:1180/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:126/200(L)--   --dict:179/300(L)--
>
> Current allocation mode is local
>
> Current file position is 601489
>
> GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
>
> PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
>
> ==> 2 pages written on `bug0001-problem-pics.pdf'.

I am still tracking down the problem I experienced in a real project: I haven't got the barcodes at all. The `realproject.pdf` file was empty and therefore `pdfcrop` generated an error and there was no cropped version of the PDF file. My project is huge, so I wasn't able to emulate my real situation on a small scale yet. If I do, I'll extend this Question. Still, I couldn't hand over the TeX code generating this sort of error to a TeXist/publisher, because I wasn't able to hide it by `\batchmode` or `\nonstopmode`.

My question is: How to fix it when TikZ 3 is loaded to get no error message of this kind as in TikZ 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run it with `pdflatex --shell-escape`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\ifpdf\usepackage{tikz}\fi 
\begin{document}

My first barcode is:\par
\begin{pspicture}(3,1in)
\psbarcode{978-80-87106-00-6}{includetext guardwhitespace}{isbn}
\end{pspicture}\par
My first QR code is:\par
\begin{pspicture}(1,1in)
\psbarcode{http://www.cstug.cz/}{}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}\par
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{Hello World!};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

or run it with `xelatex` and

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
[...]
```

Comment: And how does it work with `LuaLaTeX`? I get the error `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty:93: Package catchfile Error:` Is not only me?

Answer (score 1):

It is better not to know how much time I spent on this one in a real project with deadline as I was getting no barcodes after upgrading the TeX Live distribution/TikZ. Of course, I could use a separate TeX file just for the barcodes, well, I wanted to solve it.

The problem is causing TikZ 3 for sure, because my code is running with TikZ 2. The `auto-pst-pdf` package is calling for the `pst-pdf` package and it calls for the system shell (`latex->dvips->ps2pdf->pdfcrop`). I basically limited loading of the TikZ 3 package when generating the DVI output by wrapping the `\usepackage{tikz}` command by `\ifpdf ... \fi` or alternatively for instance in `lualatex` by `\ifcsname directlua\endcsname ... \fi`. If we generate a PDF file (the actual typesetting) the TikZ 3 package is loaded, if we generate a DVI file (generating the barcodes in the system shell) we skip that loading. Then there is no error message:

> PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
>
> ==> 2 pages written on `bug0001-solution-pics.pdf'.

I enclose my solution and a page preview.

```
%! pdflatex or xelatex or lualatex
%! with ----shell-escape or --enable-write18
%! bug0001-solution.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\ifpdf
% This is another approach when running lualatex:
% \ifcsname directlua\endcsname
\usepackage{tikz}
% Plus loading tikz libraries...
\else
% Or run \batchmode or \nonstopmode as pst-pdf does...
\newenvironment{tikzpicture}[1]{}{}
\def\tikzset{}
\fi 
\begin{document}
My first barcode is:\par
\begin{pspicture}(3,1in)
\psbarcode{978-80-87106-00-6}{includetext guardwhitespace}{isbn}
\end{pspicture}\par
My first QR code is:\par
\begin{pspicture}(1,1in)
\psbarcode{http://www.cstug.cz/}{}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}\par
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{Hello World!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: a solution]